# C# implicitly changing the timezone in DateTime object

Tags: c#

I am using the following statement

```
DateTime myDateTime = new DateTime(2014, 06, 25, 20, 59, 59, 0000)
```

But when I doing this `myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:sszzz")`, it return the string `2014-06-25T08:59:59+05:30`.

How can I keep it the same to the initialization that I did, keeping the timezone same?

Comment: Why do you think it's different?

Comment: Use capital H in the tostring.

Comment: It is implicitly changing the timezone

Comment: If you want to show milliseconds, use fff, not zzz.

Answer (score 2):

From what I see you want to use round-trip date/time pattern in which case you can use

```
myDateTime.ToString("o");
```

and then you can specify `DateTimeKind` when you create your `DateTime`

```
DateTime myDateTime = new DateTime(2014, 06, 25, 20, 59, 59, 0000, DateTimeKind.Utc);
//"2014-06-25T20:59:59.0000000Z"
```

which will include `Z` at the end or

```
DateTime myDateTime = new DateTime(2014, 06, 25, 20, 59, 59, 0000, DateTimeKind.Local);
//"2014-06-25T20:59:59.0000000+01:00"
```

which will include `+05:30` (in your case)

Comment: Thanks but it is also changing the timezone. 0000 -> 0530

Comment: Would the `ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture /*or other*/)` path on the other side of the round-trip be another way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain an offset you should really be using `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`. DateTime does not have any concept of timezone only whether its Kind is Local or Utc.

```
var dto = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2014-06-25T08:59:59+05:30");
Console.WriteLine(dto); // prints 6/25/2014 8:59:59 AM +05:30
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using capital **H**, as in..

```
myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz")
```

If you want just the seconds, take out the *zzz*

```
myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Thanks but it is also changing the timezone. 0000 -> 0530

Comment: What is the locale of the machine / server?

Comment: its India but I am making an API call and want to keep the same time zone variable entered by user.

Comment: You need to add this information to the question.  So, you want to save the timezone the request came from?

Comment: yes, I want to keep it the same as to what user supplied